# nginx proxy is not working using subdomain

Tags: nginx, proxy

i have two domains

**alpha.mydomain.com** and **api-alpha.mydomain.com**

I am trying to use nginx as a proxy

i am getting the error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api-alpha.mydomain.com/dup-check'
>   from origin 'https://alpha.mydomain.com' has been blocked by CORS
>   policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control
>   check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
>   requested resource.

i would think based on my setup , the request should not be using **api-alpha.mydomain.com** but 127.0.0.1 (and not getting the CORS error)

*NOTE:: i am using cloudflare https so the console errors are https by cloudflare is the SSL and talking to port 80 to my nginx server*

this is part of my nginx config

```
   server {
        listen        80;
        server_name   alpha.mydomain.com ;

        access_log   /var/log/nginx.access_log  main;

        root /home/mydomain/react-front/dist;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

    }
   server {
        listen        80;
        server_name   api-alpha.mydomain.com ;

        access_log   /var/log/nginx-api-alpha-access.log  main;

        location /{
                proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:4001/;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }

    }
```

This is the entry from the nginx-api-alpha-access.log

> "OPTIONS /dup-check HTTP/1.1" 502 750 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36" "-"

This is the entry from /var/log/nginx/error.log

> [error] 1280#1280: *12 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.xx.xxx.xxx, server: api-mydomain.trigfig.com, request: "OPTIONS /dup-check HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:4001/dup-check", host: "api-alpha.mydomain.com"

Thanks, not sure what i am missing in my config

Answer (score 0):

try change to

```
server {
        listen        80;
        server_name   alpha.mydomain.com ;

        access_log   /var/log/nginx.access_log  main;

        root /home/mydomain/react-front/dist;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

    }
   server {
        listen        80;
        server_name   api-alpha.mydomain.com ;

        access_log   /var/log/nginx-api-alpha-access.log  main;

        location /{

            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 204;
             }

             add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
             add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE';
             add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization';
             add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range,Authorization';

                proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:4001/;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I think `add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'alpha.mydomain.com';` should be enough for this case.